# How to join a image after last frame of a video using melt/MLT

Tags: command-line, video-editing, melt

How do I join a image to video using melt command or MTL framework?
I tried

```
melt video1.wmv video2.png -consumer avformat:output.wmv
```

this command do my task but output video shows image frame for very long time. how can I control duration for image file (video2.png)? I want to show this image for only few seconds, say 3 seconds

I followed this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&list=PLcUid3OP_4OWC-GJ6KfHK7dIK_yRKKn0e&v=q0KnhkbFl_s).

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution:

```
melt video1.wmv in=1 out=120 video2.png in=1 out=90 -consumer avformat:file.wmv
```

The final video will have 120 frames of `video1.wmv` and only 90 frames out of all frames of `video2.png`.

I followed [this tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eQ7NzcxV3NA).